# CommonErrorHandler not present in kafka spring?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I have created a simple kafka consumer as

```
@EnableKafka
@Configuration
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {

@Bean
public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
    Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, "127.0.0.1:9092");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "group_id");
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
    props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG,StringDeserializer.class);
    return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
}

@Bean
public ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> 
  kafkaListenerContainerFactory() {
    ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> factory =
      new ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<>();
    factory.setConsumerFactory(consumerFactory());
    return factory;
}
}
```

This is kafka consumer

```
@Component
public class KafkaConsumer {

@KafkaListener(topics = "NewTopic", groupId = "group_id")
public void consume(String message) {
    System.out.println("message = " + message);
}
}
```

When I run the application get the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaAnnotationDrivenConfiguration': Unexpected exception during bean creation; nested exception is java.lang.TypeNotPresentException: Type org.springframework.kafka.listener.CommonErrorHandler not present
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is the problem of versions compatibility.

Please, consider to not override `spring-kafka` version, but rely on what Spring Boot provides for us.

The `CommonErrorHandler` has been introduced since Spring for Apache Kafka `2.8`. According your `5.3.21` version for Spring Framework in logs, it looks like you use Spring Boot 2.6.x or even `2.7.x`. But at the same time you use an old Spring for Apache Kafka version and really with an explicit version.